# How to bind a button on wpf grid to a method on MVVM when I am using caliburn micro

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, caliburn.micro

I have a Grid on a wpf window which I want to add the capability that user can delete some of the items by clicking on a delete button. The application uses Calibrun Micro to bind view to ViewModel.

My question?

1- Is it a good idea to use a button to delete an item from a grid in WPF?

2- How can I bind a button to a method on VM and in the methd get a pointer to the item that should be deleted?

### **Edit1**

I added the buttons in this way to datagrid:

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn Width="100">
    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Button Content="Delete" cal:Message.Attach="DeleteFromList($dataContext)" />
         </DataTemplate>
     </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
 </DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

and c# code follow:

```
 public void DeleteFromList(object tmp)
    {

    }
```

But the buttons on datagrid are disabled and clicking on them doesn't fire DeleteFromList method (I checked using debugger).

Why they are disabled? How can I make them enabled?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This depends on how your button is placed - is there a single 'delete' button or have you added a button per row in the grid (are we talking `DataGrid` or just `Grid`?)

Assuming you are talking about `DataGrid`, you can easily just add an action message command to the button and pass through the item which is being deleted to the message handler on the VM

e.g. in the VM

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    public DataItemCollectionTypeName ItemCollection { get; set; }

    public void DeleteItem(DataItemTypeName item)
    {
        ItemCollection.Remove(item);
    }
}
```

Assuming `ItemCollection` is bound to the grid, the button XAML may look like this:

```
<Button cal:Message.Attach="[Click] = [DeleteItem($datacontext)]" />
```

You may also need to set `Action.TargetWithoutContext` (it should be bound to the VM) if this is a templated row, as otherwise CM will not be able to locate the VM to invoke the action message on

If you have a single button that isn't contained within the grid you can always target the grids `SelectedItem` in the action message

```
<DataGrid x:Name="SomeDataGrid"></DataGrid>
<Button cal:Message.Attach="[Click] = [DeleteItem(SomeDataGrid.SelectedItem)]" />
```

It may be (and probably is) the default property that CM will look at so you may not need to specify the property name unless you have modified default conventions

```
<DataGrid x:Name="SomeDataGrid"></DataGrid>
<Button cal:Message.Attach="[Click] = [DeleteItem(SomeDataGrid)]" />
```

**Edit**

To clarify: In order for CM to find a VM to call the `DeleteItem` method it uses the `DataContext` of the current item. In the case of an `ItemsControl` derived control, the datacontext for each item points to the item being bound, not the ViewModel.

In order to give CM a hint as to which object it should try to resolve the `DeleteItem` method on, you can use the `Action.TargetWithoutContext` attached property, which applies a target object for action messages without changing the `DataContext` of the bound row/item

You can use element name syntax to point to the correct place:

In this example I've used a grid as the root element and named it `LayoutRoot`, then I've pointed the action message target to `LayoutRoot.DataContext` (which will be the ViewModel) using `ElementName` syntax. You can use any method (`AncestorType` or whatever)

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">
    <DataGridTemplateColumn Width="100">
        <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Button Content="Delete" cal:Message.Attach="DeleteFromList($dataContext)" cal:Action.TargetWithoutContext="{Binding DataContext, ElementName=LayoutRoot}" />
             </DataTemplate>
         </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
     </DataGridTemplateColumn>
</Grid>
```

That should then work!

Comment: Thanks. Can you please give me more information about "You may also need to set Action.TargetWithoutContext (it should be bound to the VM) if this is a templated row, as otherwise CM will not be able to locate the VM to invoke the action message on" since my button is disable and clicking on it doesn't fire my method on VM.

Comment: thank you! I had a similar question ( http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19679804/wpf-ribbon-fluentdropdownbutton-caliburn-micro-event/ ) and this made it clear! I also posted my solution

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this...

```
<Button cal:Message.Attach="[Event MouseEnter] = [Action Save($this)]">
```

Check the docs as they will explain what you need to do and should answer your question: [link](https://caliburnmicro.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Cheat%20Sheet&referringTitle=Documentation)